# How does the Google Docs PDF Viewer allow copy and paste?

Tags: web-applications, pdf, google-docs

Google's PDF viewer allows text selection. I understand how the user isn't actually selecting text but simply "drawing" rectangles on top of a PNG image. However, when the user hits CTRL+C, the "selected" text is copied into the user's clipboard.

I realize that this could be possible using Adobe Flash but Google's solution seems to work  even if you do not have Adobe Flash installed.

How does Google do this ?

see : http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://labs.google.com/papers/bigtable-osdi06.pdf
for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Probably Javascript. Bind Ctrl+C to a function that acquires the OCR'd text in the given region and tells the browser to put it on the clipboard.

As to how that's done, [this](http://brooknovak.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/accessing-the-system-clipboard-with-javascript/) might be informative.